# Remove all files except some from a directory

Tags: bash, rm

When using `sudo rm -r`, how can I delete all files, with the exception of the following:

```
textfile.txt
backup.tar.gz
script.php
database.sql
info.txt
```

Comment: Sounds like a question for http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: There are 2 ways to read this question, and the existing answers cover both interpretations: EITHER: (a) preserve files with the specified names _directly_ located in the target directory and - as `rm -r` implies - _delete everything else, including subdirectories_ - even if they contain files with the specified names; OR: (b) traverse the entire subtree of the target directory and, in each directory, delete all files except those with the names listed.

Comment: To everyone doing this, *please make a backup first*. I've just wasted several days worth of work because I forgot to exclude `.git`, and not having pushed, I was unable to recover over 30 commits. Make sure you exclude everything you care about, hidden folders included. And set `-maxdepth 1` if you're dealing with directories.

Comment: @Jason [Remove all files/directories except for one file - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/153862/209677)

Answer (score 243):

```
find [path] -type f -not -name 'textfile.txt' -not -name 'backup.tar.gz' -delete
```

If you don't specify `-type f` find will also list directories, which you may not want.

---

Or a more general solution using the very useful combination `find | xargs`:

```
find [path] -type f -not -name 'EXPR' -print0 | xargs -0 rm --
```

for example, delete all non txt-files in the current directory:

```
find . -type f -not -name '*txt' -print0 | xargs -0 rm --
```

The `print0` and `-0` combination is needed if there are spaces in any of the filenames that should be deleted.

Comment: it seems xargs has a text size limit

Comment: to delete multiple patterns : `find . -type f -not -name '*ignore1' -not -name '*ignore2' | xargs rm`

Comment: what about directories? it will delete all files, but does it remove folders?!

Comment: @emab: It will not delete directories, that's what the "-type f" does.

Comment: Instead of "| xargs rm", find takes a -delete parameter.

Comment: Another couple of items that will reduce (probably) unwanted side effects: add `-not -name ".*" -maxdepth 1` to protect configuration and version control metadata.

Comment: it might be worth adding a -f  after the rm, (ie. `rm -f --`) as this command throws a `rm: missing operand` error otherwise which may be problematic if the command is used in a script.

Comment: instead of `-print0 | xargs -0 rm --` you can just `-delete`

Comment: maybe somebody could make a bash function to remove everything except the arguments given and add it to the .bashrc. for example `rme textfile.txt backup.tar.gz`

Comment: using `-delete` but removing `-type f` is actually really handy, because it deletes all directories which end up empty from deleting the files, but keeps the ones that happen to have your kept files in them

Answer (score 158):

```
rm !(textfile.txt|backup.tar.gz|script.php|database.sql|info.txt)
```

The extglob (Extended Pattern Matching) needs to be enabled in BASH (if it's not enabled):

```
shopt -s extglob
```

Comment: I get "syntax error near unexpected token \`('" when I do `shopt -s extglob; rm -rf !(README|LICENSE)`. Any idea why?

Comment: @nic I don't remember, sorry. I probably ended up using `find` with the `-delete` option.

Comment: This is the best solution for me and it works by default on my Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS with no need for shopt

Comment: @xtian: `extglob` is OFF by default, so if you find it's on already, something must have turned it on, such as your bash profile (either directly or by sourcing a script that turns it on, which happens with careless 3rd-party scripts).

Comment: @nic, @Dennis: The syntax error suggests that something OTHER than `bash` was used, e.g., `dash`, where `extglob` is not supported. However, in an _interactive_ `bash` shell, the command will ALSO not work as stated, though for different reasons. The short of it: execute `shopt -s extglob` BY ITSELF; ONCE SUCCESSFULLY ENABLED (verify with `shopt extglob`), execute `rm -rf !(README|LICENSE)`. (While `extglob` is not yet enabled, `!(...)` is evaluated by _history expansion_ BEFORE the commands are executed; since this likely fails, NEITHER command is executed, and `extglob` is never turned on.)

Comment: @nic, @Dennis, @mklement0: I had the same issue with "syntax error near unexpected token (" when executing the command within a .sh file (#! /bin/bash) but not when I was running it in a command line interface. It turned out that in addition to the `shopt -s extglob` run in the command line interface, I had to rerun it inside my script file. This solved the problem for me.

Comment: if someone would like to combine it, it's not always good idea. `rm -rf * .* !(src/|lost+found/)` <-- it didn't work as I expect, it deleted everything ;)

Comment: Deleted everything for me on OSX/zsh

Comment: This works perfectly as long as there is only one of these. If I try to use two, the second one does not work, but gives weird paths with /./ in the middle.

Answer (score 43):

`find . | grep -v "excluded files criteria" | xargs rm`

This will list all files in current directory, then list all those that don't match your criteria (beware of it matching directory names) and then remove them.

**Update**: based on your edit, if you really want to delete everything from current directory except files you listed, this can be used:

```
mkdir /tmp_backup && mv textfile.txt backup.tar.gz script.php database.sql info.txt /tmp_backup/ && rm -r && mv /tmp_backup/* . && rmdir /tmp_backup
```

It will create a backup directory `/tmp_backup` (you've got root privileges, right?), move files you listed to that directory, delete recursively everything in current directory (you know that you're in the right directory, do you?), move back to current directory everything from `/tmp_backup` and finally, delete `/tmp_backup`.

I choose the backup directory to be in root, because if you're trying to delete everything recursively from root, your system will have big problems.

Surely there are more elegant ways to do this, but this one is pretty straightforward.

Comment: Works also really well with egrep, e.g. for cleaning intermediate latex files: `find . | egrep -v "\.tex|\.bib" | xargs rm`

Comment: amazing command! for removing directories just change to rm -r

Comment: If you want to simply delete everything in the current directory other than the excluded criteria: `find . -maxdepth 1 | grep -v "exclude these" | xargs rm -r` works much faster as it doesn't need to drill down in to directories unnecessarily.

Comment: Re `find` pipeline: efficiency issues aside (3 commands are used for what `find` could do alone), this will not work as intended with filenames with embedded spaces and will potentially delete the wrong files.

Comment: A command that stores "to-be-saved" files in another location (`/tmp_backup`) doesn't end well if it's interrupted—from the user's perspective, *all* the files have vanished, unless they know where to go looking for them to get them back. For that reason I'm not in favour of this type of strategy.

Answer (score 27):

I prefer to use sub query list:

```
rm -r `ls | grep -v "textfile.txt\|backup.tar.gz\|script.php\|database.sql\|info.txt"`
```

> -v, --invert-match        select non-matching lines
>
> `\|` Separator

To avoid preserving files with similar names:

```
rm -r `ls | grep -v "^textfile.txt$\|^backup.tar.gz$"`
```

Comment: Elegant solution

Comment: My favorite solution here ;)

Comment: This is really error prone. e.g. it will preserve files named `old-textfile.txt`, etc.

Comment: @istepaniuk, Good point! I've updated with an advanced usage.

Comment: And if I want to do it the other way around, say preserve the matching files? Removing the `-v` gives `rm: missing operand`

Answer (score 20):

Assuming that files with those names exist in multiple places in the directory tree and you want to preserve all of them:

```
find . -type f ! -regex ".*/\(textfile.txt\|backup.tar.gz\|script.php\|database.sql\|info.txt\)" -delete
```

Answer (score 19):

You can use GLOBIGNORE environment variable in Bash.

Suppose you want to delete all files except php and sql, then you can do the following -

```
export GLOBIGNORE=*.php:*.sql
rm *
export GLOBIGNORE=
```

Setting GLOBIGNORE like this ignores php and sql from wildcards used like "ls *" or "rm *". So, using "rm *" after setting the variable will delete only txt and tar.gz file.

Comment: +1; A simpler alternative to setting and restoring the `GLOBIGNORE` variable is to use a subshell: `(GLOBIGNORE='*.php:*.sql'; rm *)`

Answer (score 9):

Since nobody mentioned it:

- copy the files you don't want to delete in a safe place
- delete all the files
- move the copied files back in place

Comment: It is more complicate because you have to take care of permissions after you copy them back.

Comment: @RemusAvram You can use appropriate switches with `cp` or `rsync` to preserve permissions. Anyways, this is just an alternate method (given as a suggestion) that has its place here, as an answer to the OP.

Comment: This may not be appropriate in many situations wherein the files to be retained are actively being used by other processes.  It is also cumbersome of the files to be removed are just a small subset and a large number of files are involved.

Comment: @codeforester: sure. But there are situations where it's appropriate, though... in fact I don't really see the point of your comment `:)`.

Answer (score 7):

You can write a for loop for this... %)

```
for x in *
do
        if [ "$x" != "exclude_criteria" ]
        then
                rm -f $x;
        fi
done;
```

Answer (score 6):

A little late for the OP, but hopefully useful for anyone who gets here much later by google...

I found the answer by @awi and comment on -delete by @Jamie Bullock really useful. A simple utility so you can do this in different directories ignoring different file names/types each time with minimal typing:

rm_except (or whatever you want to name it)

```
#!/bin/bash

ignore=""

for fignore in "$@"; do
  ignore=${ignore}"-not -name ${fignore} "
done

find . -type f $ignore -delete
```

e.g. to delete everything except for text files and foo.bar:

```
rm_except *.txt foo.bar
```

Similar to @mishunika, but without the if clause.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using [`zsh`](http://www.zsh.org/) which I highly recommend.

```
rm -rf ^file/folder pattern to avoid
```

With `extended_glob`

```
setopt extended_glob
rm -- ^*.txt
rm -- ^*.(sql|txt)
```

Answer (score 4):

Trying it worked with:

```
rm -r !(Applications|"Virtualbox VMs"|Downloads|Documents|Desktop|Public)
```

but names with spaces are (as always) tough.  Tried also with `Virtualbox\ VMs` instead the quotes.  It deletes always that directory (`Virtualbox VMs`).

Comment: Does NOT work for files. `rm !(myfile.txt)` removes all including `myfile.txt`

Comment: should execute `shopt -s extglob` first as @pl1nk pointed out

Comment: Yes, it's very important to activate extended globbing (*extglob*) in bash, I am doing this in a daily routine basis, over a few Macs in labs:

`shopt -s extglob` and then `cd /Users/alumno/` and finally `rm -rf !(Applications|Virtualbox*VMs|Downloads|Documents|Desktop|Public|Library)`

Read about extended globbing [here](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-extended-globbing)

Answer (score 4):

Just:

```
rm $(ls -I "*.txt" ) #Deletes file type except *.txt
```

Or:

```
rm $(ls -I "*.txt" -I "*.pdf" ) #Deletes file types except *.txt & *.pdf
```

Comment: This is not recommended. Parsing `ls` output can become a problem is.
See [Here](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) for detailed information.

Answer (score 2):

Make the files immutable. Not even root will be allowed to delete them.

```
chattr +i textfile.txt backup.tar.gz script.php database.sql info.txt
rm *
```

All other files have been deleted.
Eventually you can reset them mutable.

```
chattr -i *
```

Answer (score 1):

I belive you can use

```
rm -v !(filename)
```

Except for the filename all the other files will e deleted in the directory and make sure you are using it in

Comment: Use this below command this works for me. find . -type f \! -name '*filepattern*' -print0 | xargs --null rm -f

Comment: This option only works with the extglob shell option enabled, i.e: $ shopt -s extglob

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to the comment from @siwei-shen but you need the `-o` flag to do multiple patterns.  The `-o` flag stands for 'or'

`find . -type f -not -name '*ignore1' -o -not -name '*ignore2' | xargs rm`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with two command sequences.
First define an array with the name of the files you do not want to exclude:

```
files=( backup.tar.gz script.php database.sql info.txt )
```

After that, loop through all files in the directory you want to exclude, checking if the filename is in the array you don't want to exclude; if its not then delete the file.

```
for file in *; do
  if [[ ! " ${files[@]} " ~= "$file"  ]];then
    rm "$file"
  fi
done
```

Comment: The regex comparison is incorrect -- it will preserve any file whose name is a substring of one of the protected files (though the surrounding spaces somewhat mitigate that; but file names can contain spaces). You should collect an array of all files, then subtract the files you want to exclude from that array, then remove the remaining files.

Answer (score 0):

The answer I was looking for was to run script, but I wanted to avoid deleting the sript itself. So incase someone is looking for a similar answer, do the following.

Create a .sh file and write the following code:

```
    cp my_run_build.sh ../../ 
    rm -rf * cp  
    ../../my_run_build.sh . 
    /*amend rest of the script*/
```

Answer (score -1):

Since no one yet mentioned this, in one particular case:

```
OLD_FILES=`echo *`
... create new files ...
rm -r $OLD_FILES
```

(or just `rm $OLD_FILES`)

or

```
OLD_FILES=`ls *`
... create new files ...
rm -r $OLD_FILES
```

You may need to use `shopt -s nullglob` if some files may be either there or not there:

```
SET_OLD_NULLGLOB=`shopt -p nullglob`
shopt -s nullglob
FILES=`echo *.sh *.bash`
$SET_OLD_NULLGLOB
```

without nullglob, `echo *.sh *.bash` may give you "a.sh b.sh *.bash".

(Having said all that, I myself prefer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45628487/755804), even though it does not work in OSX)

Comment: The existing answer by Leonardo Hermoso does this with fewer bugs. This will fail for file names with spaces; using an array elegantly solves that particular problem (and also less crucially avoids using uppercase for his private variables, which is generally to be avoided).

Answer (score -4):

Rather than going for a direct command, please move required files to temp dir outside current dir. Then delete all files using `rm *` or `rm -r *`.

Then move required files to current dir.

Comment: This may not be appropriate in many situations wherein the files to be retained are actively being used by other processes.  It is also cumbersome of the files to be removed are just a small subset and a large number of files are involved.

Answer (score -4):

Remove everything exclude file.name:

```
ls -d /path/to/your/files/* |grep -v file.name|xargs rm -rf
```

Comment: This will fail horribly and might cause data loss if your directory/files have spaces or unusual characters. You should never parse ls.
https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs