# Remove folder with special character on it

Tags: linux, directory, special-characters, rename

I accidentally created some folders with special characters. I already read the other posts in stackoverflow, but don't work. When I type the `ls -la` command I see

```
root@mycomputer:/myfolder# ls -la
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 feb  6 17:53 ,
drwxr-xr-x 70 root root  4096 feb 11 10:27 .
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root  4096 feb 11 09:16 ..
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root  4096 feb  9 22:45 (
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 feb  2 22:01 [
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 feb  6 08:11 $
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 feb  2 23:15 \
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root  4096 feb  8 10:34 &
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root  4096 feb  8 09:43 #
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 feb  6 14:41 +
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root  4096 feb  6 09:15 ?
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root  4096 feb  6 04:07 ?
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root  4096 feb  6 01:13 ?
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 feb  6 02:25 ?
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root  4096 feb  3 12:25 ?
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root  4096 feb  5 23:18 ?
```

I can't do anything with the ones pointed as question marks

I tried to type the command `mv` and then press `tab` and this is what I get

```
root@mycomputer:/myfolder# mv
,/                 ▒/                 7/                 h/
(/                 ▒/                 8/                 i/
[/                 ▒/                 9/                 j/
$/                 ▒/                 
\/                 ▒/
```

So apparently I can't rename them in order to delete them.

Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried escaping the character with a backslash?

Comment: the thing is that, i don't know what character it is

Comment: have you tried changing your locale? LANG=en_US.UTF-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What finally worked for me was one of the answers I found in this question:

[rm all files except some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325216/rm-all-files-except-some)

```
rm !(textfile.txt|backup.tar.gz|script.php|database.sql|info.txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the other directories, you can just

```
rmdir ?
```

Or, use character class (supported e.g. in bash):

```
rmdir [^789hij]  # removes all one-character directories except for 7, 9, etc.
```

You can also try `mc` or some other file manager.

Comment: I like this one, i guess y can type all the alphabet and the numbers and will work, right?