# How to delete file.* but keep file.txt?

Tags: bash, wildcard, delete-file

In bash, how to delete all the files starting with `file` using `file*` but keep `file.txt`?

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325216/rm-all-files-except-some)

`shopt -s extglob`

`rm file* !(file.txt)`

But the `file.txt` is still deleted.

PS: I only need to delete the files starting with `file`, not all the files. E.g. I want a file named `food.txt` still kept.

Comment: Better asked @ https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the "negative" pattern match as the file extension:

```
$ ls file.*
file.csv  file.json  file.txt  file.xml

$ ls file.!(txt)
file.csv  file.json  file.xml
```

Comment: If you get an error like `bash: !: event not found`, enable bash's extended globbing with `shopt -s extglob`

Answer (score 1):

The `find` command can help you here. For example:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -not -name 'file.*' -not -name '*.txt' -delete
```

Comment: but I only need to delete the files starting with `file`, not all the files.

Comment: Apologies. Was hasty. Modified suggestion and tested.

Answer (score 1):

**`find`** approach:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'file*' ! -name "file.txt" -delete
```