# Linux: how to remove all the files in a folder except ones with specific names?

Tags: linux, rm

I have a folder in linux that contains `.csv` files of the results of some simulations.

The name of the files are like:

```
run_0_0.020000_0.010000_15.0_10.0_T0_RealNet.csv
run_0_0.030000_0.090000_10.0_10.0_T0_RealNet.csv
run_0_0.030000_0.080000_12.0_10.0_T0_RealNet.csv
```

I want to remove all the files except the ones with `15.0_10.0_T0_`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove all files except some from a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325216/remove-all-files-except-some-from-a-directory)

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `find` command with its built in -delete feature but probably simpler if you just `$ cp /path/to/dir/*15.0_10.0_T0_* /other/dir` then remove the original directory. You can then move the new directory in place of the original. You can remove the old directory with all its contents at once with `$ rm -rf /path/to/dir`.

Answer (score 1):

For example, if you dont want to delete files that contain 15.0_10.0_T0_, you can use find:

```
find . -type f ! -name '*15.0_10.0_T0_*' -delete
```

Answer (score 0):

Another variant to remove everything but the requested files:

```
ls --ignore="*15.0_10.0_T0_*" | xargs rm
```

Or a shortened, don't ask and remove also dir version (take with care :) ):

```
ls -I "*15.0_10.0_T0_*" | xargs rm -rf
```

Answer (score -2):

use mv /dire/15.0_10.0_T0_* to destination dir
then delete whole directory by using sudo rm -rf directory name.
Hope it works.