# Bash - For loop , exclude files with specific pattern in filename right before filetype

Tags: bash

I am trying to run a for loop but trying to exclude files with a specific pattern in the filename. This is the command I am using:

```
for file in /home/ubuntu/discovery/download/*![.en].mp4; do
```

I would like this filename to be included:

```
Blub - S03E10 - Nervous Breakdown.mp4
```

but this filename to be excluded

```
Blub - S03E10 - Nervous Breakdown.en.mp4
```

Can't get it to work. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would suggest you use `find` to generate a list of desired files (sans exclusions) and then feed this list to a `while/read` loop, eg, `while read -r fname; do do_some_stuff_with_fname; done < <(find /home/unbuntu/discovery/download ... exclude_some_file_types ...)`

Comment: @markp-fuso Syntaxe of questioni is close than correct! See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75891852/1765658)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another alternative could be:

```
shopt -s nullglob
for file in /home/ubuntu/discovery/download/*{[^n],[^e]n,[^.]en}.mp4
do
# ...
done
```

Answer (score 2):

> What am I doing wrong?

Standard globbing has no grouping or group negation operators (though the extended version has these).  In your particular context, I would just filter out the unwanted files inside the loop:

```
for file in /home/ubuntu/discovery/download/*.mp4; do
  case $file in
    *.en.mp4) continue;;
  esac

  # ...
done
```

And that should work in any Bourne-family shell, not just Bash.

Answer (score 1):

#### Pathname Expansion: *"match not"*, with *`extglob`* enabled:

> ```
>          !(pattern-list)
>                 Matches anything except one of the given patterns
> ```

Try this:

```
for file in /home/ubuntu/discovery/download/!(*.en).mp4; do
    ...
```

Comment: If there are no files matching the glob pattern, `file` will be set to the glob pattern. Either verify that the path in `file` exists or enable `nullglob` with `shopt -s nullglob`.

Comment: Correct., but this is same behaviour than `/path/*`! You coud test by using `[ -$àfile ]`...

Comment: One question: why does `!(*.en).mp4` work, but not `*!(.en).mp4` ?

Comment: @Philippe because ***pattern*** have to begin by `!`. Aka `!(...)` is correct, `*!( ...)`  is an unknown pattern. See [Remove all files except some from a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15232634/1765658)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to iterate over all files, skipping any that have undesirable name patterns. Just make sure to also handle the case where no files are found, because in that case, `file` is set equal to the glob pattern. Often you can handle that situation by verifying that the path in `file` actually exists (`-e "${file}"`).

```
for file in /home/ubuntu/discovery/download/*.mp4; do
    [[ -e "${file}" && "${file}" != *.en.mp4 ]] || continue
    echo ${file}
done
```